# Почему блок опускается ниже при добавлении содержимого внутрь него?

Tags: html, css

Есть 3 блока, почему-то когда я добавляю какое-то содержимое к любому из них, этот блок опускается вниз. Никак не могу понять почему

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  background: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hel</div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Вот этот красный блок(в котором есть содержимое) опускается вниз, в то время когда другие два блока в одном ряду. Не пойму почему так происходит

Comment: Ответ, указанный ниже подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Элемент `inline-block` можно представить в виде текста. поэтому в вашем случае достаточно задать выравнивание(по аналогии с текстом):

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Это позволит выровнять блоки по верхнему краю. [Подробнее тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/137582/)